# Grab different values from a complicated string

Tags: string, postgresql, split

I have a context_data column in my Database (Postgressql) i work with that includes a lot of info i need in a string. The problem is a don't need all the information and i have to be able to just grab a couple of values from the Context data.

This is an example of how the string could look like:

```
[["+","sec_nr",null],["+","code_cd","1"],["+","lock",null],["+","action",null],["+","created_at","2021-0927T07:17:37.705+02:00"],["+","birthday",null],["+","city",null],["+","id",188715],["+","active",true],["+","kontakte",[]],{"sale":null,"skonto":null,"skonto_day":null,"skonto_info":null,"credit_bw_cd":null,"is_locked":null}],["+","lock_version",0],["+","marken_name",null],["+","name","Donald"],["+","referenz","190953"],["+","updated_at","2021-09-27T07:17:37.705+02:00"],["+","first_name","Max"]
```

And here a little more visible:

```
[["+","sec_nr",null],
["+","code_cd","1"],
["+","lock",null],
["+","action",null],
["+","created_at","2021-09-27T07:17:37.705+02:00"],
["+","birthday",null],
["+","city",null],
["+","id",188715],
["+","active",true],
["+","kontakte",[]],
{"sale":null,"skonto":null,"skonto_day":null,"skonto_info":null,"credit_bw_cd":null,"is_locked ":null}],
["+","lock_version",0],
["+","marken_name",null],
["+","name","Donald"],
["+","referenz","190953"],
["+","updated_at","2021-09-27T07:17:37.705+02:00"],
["+","first_name","Max"]
```

As i can see there is no real structure like in an xml or json or something.
What i need to be able to do is to get the info's that there has been an insert (+) of a person Max Donald with the new ID 188715.

how can i solve this the best way?

The  best output would be like  this:

```
"action"    id  first_name  last_name

+   188715  Max Donald
```

Comment: Is it not JSON? An array of arrays? Still not a nice format to work with of course, but at least the basic decoding is supported if that is the case.

Comment: Could be, im not able to tell if it's JSON. Im new to working with JSON files but i was guessing it's not JSON since example in the internet look different. In my string i have no { } for example i thought i json needs that.

Comment: Well, not really. A JSON array does not need braces.